# how to get listbox selected item name?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, listboxitem

How do I get the item name on listbox?

I have this code:

```
Dim x2 As Long
Dim OriginalCount2 As Long
'Store original ListBox count
  OriginalCount2 = ListBox1.ListCount
'Temporarily hide ListBox (runs faster)
  ListBox1.Visible = False
'Delete selected line items
  For x2 = OriginalCount2 - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Selected(x2) = True Then MsgBox x2
  Next x2
'Unhide ListBox
  ListBox1.Visible = True
```

But it only gets the item index.

Answer (score 0):

Would help to know what is event or action is triggering the code but this should get you started in the right direction:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim LBItem As Long
    For LBItem = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(LBItem) = True Then
            MsgBox (ListBox1.List(LBItem))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: um..how to display that on textbox?

Comment: To display on a Textbox just change:
MsgBox (ListBox1.List(LBItem)) to Textbox1 = (ListBox1.List(LBItem))
Again it would help to know more about where you came from and where you're going to with your code.